# indexing for python list of lists

Tags: python, list, indexing

I want to "address" a lists of lists using a set of indices. Below I provide some examples for the behavior Im looking for (it is heard to articulate in words, please see the example for clarity)

Suppose my list of lists is

```
lol = [[[0,1,2],[-1,2,4,5]],[[-2,-1,-3]],[[4,6,1],[1,7,-1],[-2,-4,1]]]

# print the length of some of the sublists
print len(lol) # prints 3
print len(lol[0]) #prints 2
print len(lol[0][1]) #prints 4

# print the value of some of the "leaves"
print lol[0][1][2] #prints 4
print lol[1][0][2] #prints -3
```

Question: Im looking for a function that takes the indices in the examples above and returns either the length of the sublist it finds at those indices or the value it finds at those indices; example,

```
address = [1,0,2]
print someFunction(lol,address) # prints -3

address = [0,1]
print someFunction(lol,address) # prints 4
```

I have tried writing a function but ended up with a lot of conditional statements to check if the indices point to a sublist or one of the values at the "leaves" of the nested lists.

Comment: yeah I'm fairly experienced, not so much with python. I have function to do this but It doesn't work for any size of nested lists and I have a feeling there is a very short and sweet solution.

Comment: I dont entirely agree that this question is a duplicate. First, the referenced question is for a dictionary. Also, when the listed indexes reach the "leaves" in the list the function should return the value it finds, not the length. Otherwise it returns the length. I had this in the comments but should have been more clear

Comment: Edit your question and add all the relevant information, including your attempts at solving this. Your question is close-worthy (too broad/unclear) as it stands.

Comment: FYI, someone else asked this yesterday, and got a lovely response.  I can't find it now ... I should have commented so it would be in my history.  :-(

Comment: @downshift: no, the one I saw dealt specifically with an arbitrary quantity of indices, presented as a list, to use for extraction from a nested list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple function to do what you want:

```
def get_length_or_value(l, *i):
    item = l
    for index in i:
        item = item[index]
    return len(item) if isinstance(item, list) else item
```

This function first finds the element at the given indices (if any), and then returns the appropriate value based off wether the element is a `list` type or not.

You can call it like this:
`get_length_or_value(lol)`
`get_length_or_value(lol, 0)`
`get_length_or_value(lol, 0, 1)`
`get_length_or_value(lol, 0, 1, 2)`
`get_length_or_value(lol, 1, 0, 2)`
Those calls all return the expected values you posted above.

Comment: perfect, its cool that you can also pass a list as the second argument.